# How to fix 'ORA-29909: label for the ancillary operator is not a literal number' with bound variable?

Tags: oracle, contains, oracle-text

The following SQL running of an Oracle Text CONTEXT indexed column:

```
variable label number;
exec :label := 1;
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE 
           WHERE CONTAINS(INDEXEDCOL, 'token', :label) > 0;
```

Results in:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-29909: label for the ancillary operator is not a literal number
29909. 00000 -  "label for the ancillary operator is not a literal number"
*Cause:    The label used for invoking the ancillary operator is not
           a literal number.
*Action:   Use a literal number as the label.
```

I found one mention of a similar problem here:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=91417

but altering the cursor with the following command does not help in my case:

```
ALTER SESSION SET cursor_sharing='EXACT';
```

There's also this stackoverflow question:

[ORA-29908: missing primary invocation for ancillary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352796/ora-29908-missing-primary-invocation-for-ancillary-operator)

but the answer is not applicable.
I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: I don't see any direct way to solve this problem.  You could possibly work around it by using dynamic SQL, and maybe wrapping that dynamic SQL in a pipelined function.  Although that would not be very user friendly.

Comment: Thanks! This is a result of a JPA CriteriaQuery
    Predicate p = cb.gt(cb.function("CONTAINS", Integer.class, path,
 cb.literal("token"), cb.literal(1)), 0);
so my options are fairly limited.